# How to Extract Plus simple and number from string in php

Tags: php, regex

How to extract phone number with + simple from string. My input is like +6594758744(william) my expected output is +6594758744..

So i need the extract +6594758744 from the below string types

`$str1='+6594758744 (william)'; $str2='+6594758744 (william:brother)'; $str3='+6594758744 ( william : brother )'; $str4 ='+65 94758744 ( william allan:brother )';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regular expression can capture the plus sign, followed by numbers and spaces.  And then, the resulting match can have spaces removed.  For example:

```
<?php

$strings = array(
  '+6594758744 (william)',
  '+6594758744 (william:brother)',
  '+6594758744 ( william : brother )',
  '+65 94758744 ( william allan:brother )'
);


$regexp = '/((\+)?([\d ]+))/';
foreach ($strings as $string) {
  preg_match($regexp, $string, $matches);
  print preg_replace('/ /', '', $matches[0]) . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly..No need of a Regex here.

```
<?php
$str='+6594758744(william)';
$arr = explode('(',$str);
echo $arr[0]; //"prints" +6594758744
```

or a one-liner.

```
<?php
echo array_shift(explode('(','+6594758744(william)'));
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/98940)

Comment: optional=>() for the give string Sometime my string have bracket sometime don't have bracket

Comment: Then you could just add a space instead of `(` in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `preg_replace`:

```
$s = '+65 94758744(william)';
$r = preg_replace('/^.*?(\+[\d ]+).*$/', '$1', $s);
//=> +65 94758744
```

Comment: Thank u,It working.. plz edit ur answer in second line =>$r = preg_replace('/^.*?(\+\d+).*$/', '$1', $s); u miss the comma in the argument

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, I fixed it.

Comment: but the input is +65 94758744(william allan) means output =>+65 only

Comment: sorry for delay replay the above update code also give +65 only

Answer (score 0):

let try

```
$str = '+6594758744(william) ';
echo "+" . sprintf('%.0f', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
$str='+6594758744(william)';
$output=preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$str);
echo "+".$output;
```

Comment: This will give wrong results if input is `$str='+6594758744(william 1st)';`

Comment: thanks @anubhava yes this give +6565947587441,but in my string it more rare case i'll extract the first 10 numeric..and i need to test it by give more diff values

Comment: @Anitha I also agree with anubhava.  My suggestion: rather than assume that you won't run into rare cases which will break your solution, work just a little bit harder to produce a slightly smarter solution which can handle the rare cases too.  This will make you a more effective programmer in the long run, and you'll find yourself with fewer headaches.

Comment: @Alvin Lee I get the answer by using echo "+".substr($output,0,10); and also agree ur solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this

pattern is

```
/(\+\d{10})/
```

This will capture phone number

[SEE HERE](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/3C0)